# Alternative to for and ifelse loops - determining whether elements lie within generated confidence intervals

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, confidence-interval

I am trying to rewrite my code to not contain any for loops or ifelse loops. The purpose is to extract a matrix containing 0s and 1s depending on variable *mu* and variable *cinterval* - to generate a 1 if y0 falls within its 95th CI, and 0 y0 falls within its 95th CI, and likewise for y1. This would be repeated with both y0 and y1 for a number of modules.

*mu* contains values for y0 and y1; *cinterval* contains four rows:

> 1. lower 95th CI limit for y0
> 2. upper 95th CI limit for y0
> 3. lower 95th CI limit for y1
> 4. upper 95th CI limit for y1

*cinterval* can be programmed to have any number of modules:

```
cinterval.fn <- function(y0y1modules) {
  matrix(c(y0results, y1results) nrow=4, ncol=no.of.modules, byrow=T) #simplified from true code
  rownames(cinterval) <- c("y0 95LCI", "y0 95UCI", "y1 95LCI", "y1 95UCI")
  colnames(cinterval) <- paste('module', 1:length(cinterval[1,]), sep='.')
  return(cinterval)
}

> cinterval
         module.1 module.2  module.3
y0 95LCI 2.434602 1.784056  1.751713
y0 95UCI 5.988160 6.519465  6.833455
y1 95LCI 3.778811 2.681708  2.805293
y1 95UCI 9.228941 9.716476 10.258412
```

*mu* looks like this:

```
mu <- c(4, 8)
mu
y0 y1 
 4  8
```

The code I have is:

```
incinterval.fn <- function(cov.xy, mu, n1, dr) {
  cinterval <- cintervaloutput.fn(cov.xy, mu, n1, dr) # Generates matrix with 95% CI values for y0 and y1 after modules
  y0 <- NULL   # Empty vector
  for (module.no in 1:ncol(cinterval)) {
    y0 <- cbind(y0, ifelse (cinterval[1, module.no] <= mu["y0"] || mu["y0"] <= cinterval[2, module.no], 1, 0))
  }            # If y0 inside CI, 1, else 0
  y1 <- NULL   # Empty vector
  for (module.no in 1:ncol(cinterval)) {
    y1 <- cbind(y1, ifelse (cinterval[3, module.no] <= mu["y1"] || mu["y1"] <= cinterval[4, module.no], 1, 0))
  }            # If y1 inside CI, 1, else 0
  incinterval <- rbind(y0, y1) # Combines vectors
  colnames(incinterval) <- paste('module', 1:length(cinterval[1,]), sep='.')
  return(incinterval)
}
```

The result, incinterval, looks like this:

```
     module.1 module.2 module.3
[y0]        1        1        1
[y1]        1        1        1
```

Any assistance with more efficient coding to replace for and ifelse would be greatly appreciated! I currently use 2 for and ifeelse loops.

Comment: You don't give a reproducible example, but something along the lines of `as.numeric(mu["y0"] >= cinterval[1,] & mu["y0"] <= cinterval[2,])` should do the job (and similar for y1). No need to go into ifelse and cycles.

Comment: In R, growing a vector is a bad idea. You know the size, you could make a vector of 0 and change to 1 only if needed.

Comment: Could you `dput` the `cinterval` matrix? It is quite cumbersome to write it manually.

Comment: @Ape I explained my code and gave examples of the variables involved and the outcome. I can edit my post to make it clearer if you give a suggestion :) ?

Your suggestion seems to be similar to what I already have. I think I am missing something.

Comment: @Matthew It's a good practice to provide code to generate sample of the data along with its desription, not just post how it looks like. Here you could include the result of `dput(mu)` and `dput(cinterval[,1:3])`. Otherwise anyone who wants to answer the question has to create the data sample themselves, which is unnecessary and cumbersome (as LAP notes).

Comment: @Ape Thanks for your suggestions. I added code to generate mu and cinterval to my original post. I am looking into your sapply suggestion now, will get back to you about how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @FlorianGD. I agree it's cumbersome, but I needed the 0s and 1s for later functions (specifically to generate coverage).

Comment: Thanks for the thought @LAP. I was unaware of the dput function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data:

```
cinterval <- data.frame(rbind(c(2.434602,1.784056,1.751713),
                                 c(5.988160,6.519465,6.833455),
                                 c(3.778811,2.681708,2.805293),
                                 c(9.228941,9.716476,10.258412)),
                   row.names = c("y0 L","y0 U","y1 L","y1 U") 
)
colnames(cinterval) <- paste0("module.",1:3)
mu <- c("y0" = 4, "y1" = 8)
```

You can take advantage of vectorization and compare single value with a vector

```
as.numeric(mu["y0"] >= cinterval[1,] & mu["y0"] <= cinterval[2,])

[1] 1 1 1
```

Works accordingly for "y1".

Comment: Thank you kindly for your advice for my question, and my opening post tips. This did the job perfectly, much better than I hoped for!

I adapted your suggestion as:
incinterval <- rbind(as.numeric(mu["y0"] >= cinterval[1,] & mu["y0"] <= cinterval[2,]), as.numeric(mu["y1"] >= cinterval[3,] & mu["y0"] <= cinterval[4,]))

Which worked like a charm!

Comment: You are welcome. Note that `ifelse` is also vectorized, so this would also do the job: `ifelse(mu["y0"] >= cinterval[1,] & mu["y0"] <= cinterval[2,],1,0)`. You may also want to check the difference between `||` (resp `&&`) and `|` (resp. `&`) (run e.g. ?'||').

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input data is created something like:

```
mu = c(y0 = 4, y1 = 8)

cinterval <-
    data.frame(names = c("y0", "y0", "y1", "y1"),
               CI = c("LCI", "UCI", "LCI", "UCI"),
               module.1 = c(2.434602, 5.988160, 3.778811, 9.228941),
               module.2 = c(1.784056, 6.519465, 2.681708, 9.716476),
               module.3 = c(1.751713, 6.833455, 2.805293, 10.258412))
```

Then something like this might do what you want:

```
sapply(seq_along(mu),
     function(y) {

          cis  <- cinterval[cinterval[["names"]] == names(mu)[y], -1:-2]

         apply(cis, 2, function(ci) {
              findInterval(mu[y], ci)
          })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much you depend on your data structure, but I'm proposing a different approach.

If you'd structure your dataset in another format, you could easily write the outcome of `incinterval` in an additional variable.

New data:

```
cinterval <-  data.frame(year = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
               LCI = c(2.434602, 1.784056, 1.751713, 3.778811, 2.681708, 2.805293),
               UCI = c(5.988160, 6.519465, 6.833455, 9.228941, 9.716476, 10.258412),
               module = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
               )

> cinterval
  year      LCI       UCI module
1    0 2.434602  5.988160      1
2    0 1.784056  6.519465      2
3    0 1.751713  6.833455      3
4    1 3.778811  9.228941      1
5    1 2.681708  9.716476      2
6    1 2.805293 10.258412      3
```

Now you define `mu`

```
mu <- c("y0" = 4, "y1" = 8)
```

and `apply` a short `ifelse` condition over your rows using `findInterval` to get a new column with your results:

```
cinterval$inCI <- apply(cinterval, 1, 
                        function(x) ifelse(x[1] == 0, findInterval(mu["y0"], x[2:3]), 
                                                      findInterval(mu["y1"], x[2:3]))
                        )
```

Your output:

```
  year      LCI       UCI module inCI
1    0 2.434602  5.988160      1    1
2    0 1.784056  6.519465      2    1
3    0 1.751713  6.833455      3    1
4    1 3.778811  9.228941      1    1
5    1 2.681708  9.716476      2    1
6    1 2.805293 10.258412      3    1
```

Note that `findInterval` will return either a 0 if the `mu` value was below the CI, a 1 if it was within, or a 2 if it was above the CI.

This may become cumbersome when dealing with many `years`, but is quite robust to include as many `modules` as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions and feedback.

I took Ape's suggestion as it was the simplest.

The code is now changed with bold text to:

```
incinterval.fn <- function(cov.xy, mu, n1, dr) {
  cinterval <- cintervaloutput.fn(cov.xy, mu, n1, dr) # Generates matrix with 95% CI values for y0 and y1 after treatment modules (can be any number of modules))
  **incinterval <- rbind(as.numeric(mu["y0"] >= cinterval[1,] & mu["y0"] <= cinterval[2,]),
                        as.numeric(mu["y1"] >= cinterval[3,] & mu["y0"] <= cinterval[4,]))**
  colnames(incinterval) <- paste('module', 1:length(cinterval[1,]), sep='.')
  return(incinterval)
}
```

Instead of using for loops and ifelse loops, it's using a simpler way to answer the question with generating vectors with the comparison operators.